# Regarding python error : "ImportError: cannot import name Dynamic"

Tags: python, file, import, importerror

I am facing a strange error while executing a python code. The following code is a small snippet of the python code I am executing:

```
#samplecode.py
    import time 
    from datetime import datetime 
    import sys 
    import os 
    import inspect
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname('C:\Users\qksr\Desktop\work\kako\logging.py'))
    import logging
    from logging import Dynamic
```

While executing samplecode.py I am facing an error showing the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qksr\Desktop\work\Fire\samplecode6.py", line 8, in <module>
    from logging import Dynamic
ImportError: cannot import name Dynamic
```

My logging.py which contains the code that needs to be imported while execution. The following is the code:

```
class Dynamic(object):
    pfile3=open('C:\Users\qksr\Desktop\work\sample3.txt','w')
```

we can see that the class Dynamic is created yet the import error is thrown.

The strangest thing is I did few examples of importing files and it worked well. I have tried hard but still cannot figure it out. I would like to know why this error was thrown and why suddenly for this and not in previous samples?

Comment: There's already a Python module called `logging`. Rename your file to something else.

Comment: Thanks it works fine now. So the problem is naming the file i get it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python already has a built-in `logging` module, which is being located before yours (you're appending your folder to the end of the path).

Rename your `logging.py` file to something else.